# Using Chinese Characters with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
def readTags(collection,index):
    file = open("F:\\dship\\odps-dship\\test_tag_data.txt")
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        strArr = line.split("\t")[8].split(" ")
        for index in range(len(strArr)):
            #queryTag = strArr[index]
            print(collection.find_one({"tagList":{"$all",u"手拿包"}}))
```

when my program executed ,I get the follow exception

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: set(['$all', u'\u624b\u62ff\u5305'])
```

how can i resolve it？

Comment: Could you maybe think of a less confrontational title and possibly more explanation. People respond better to a nice ask than a slap in the face. By the way `$all` takes an "array" of arguments and not a single string as a value.

Comment: Could I also suggest you include the relevant tags to your question yourself and also that those other users without the privilege for making edits without moderation approval please refrain from doing so on questions less than 10 minutes old.

Answer (score 2):

Python syntax for object notation is almost exactly the same as JSON notation as is commonly used in all the MongoDB official documentation. The only exception is "ordered dicts" where that is actually applied but it does not apply in this case since there are no keys that require a specific order.

So it's basically just following what the documentation for [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) actually says, and nothing to do with the Unicode support whatsoever:

```
print(collection.find_one({ "tagList": { "$all": [ u"手拿包" ] } }))
```

Is the correct form of the line that is actually throwing the error for you. Your MongoDB syntax was wrong, and nothing to do with Chinese characters.